# Why is the tension in Atwood machine maximized when $m_1=m_2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, string

[image]

Hi. I was just wondering why the tension in an Atwood machine would be at its maximum when the two masses hanging on both ends have equal weights. The expression for tension is 
$$T=\dfrac{2m_1m_2g}{m_1+m_2}.$$
 If we keep $m_2$ constant (say it's 3kg) and vary $m_1$ ($m_1=x$), then the equation becomes 
$$T=\dfrac{2\times3\times9.8\times x}{3+x}.$$
 When this equation is graphed, the function approaches $2\times3\times9.8$ as $x$ goes to infinity, i.e. it's not maximized when $x=3$. I don't quite get why the tension is maximized when both masses have equal weights. Could anyone help me understand this concept?

Comment: Where did you read that tension is maximum when $m_1=m_2$?

Comment: My physics professor's problem set answer key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misinterpreted what you were told. If the **total mass** $M=m_1+m_2$ is held constant then the tension $T$ is a maximum when  $m_1=m_2$.

Otherwise $T$ can be as large as you wish, as you have shown. All you need to do is make $m_1 \to \infty$ then $T \to 2m_2g$ which can take any value you choose, for a suitable value of $m_2$. In particular, you can have $T \to \infty$ if you allow $m_2 \to \infty$.

However, if $m_1+m_2=M$ is fixed then $T=2m_1(M-m_1)g/M$ which has a maximum value of $Mg$ for $m_1=m_2=\frac12 M$.